# JavaScript `of` Keyword (for...of loops)

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I just spotted, [in Firefox SDK JavaScript (on MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#Access_tabs), the use of a keyword I have never seen before:

```
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
for (let tab of tabs)
  console.log(tab.title);
```

Is the `of` keyword made up by Mozilla or is it standardized?

Comment: Part of ES6. Googling for "for of loop ES6" should turn up something.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop, which iterates over property *values*, is a feature [added to the JavaScript specification in ECMAScript 2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements).

Given that the context of this question is a Firefox add-on, the issue is not when, or if, it is available in other browsers. The issue is when this [ECMAScript 2015 feature was added to Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla) and any limitation on backward compatibility which using it causes.

It was added to Firefox in [Firefox 13](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/13#JavaScript).  Thus, using it will result in restricting your add-on to be Firefox 13+.  Given that the current release, as of October 2014, is Firefox 33.0 and there have been multiple ESR releases between Firefox 13 and now, using a `for...of` loop probably will not significantly reduce the number of people who are able to use your add-on.  It is likely that some other feature which you are using will restrict your add-on to a more recent version.

### Using `for...of`

Unlike [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), `for...of` loops are not restricted to only Arrays and will iterate over other types of [iterable objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/iterable), which includes a considerable number of different types of Objects.

One of the things that sometimes confuses people is that `for...of` iterates over property *values*, not the property key. Depending on what you are doing, this can either be quite convenient, of make it such that a `for...of` loop is inappropriate.

#### Example: `for..of` iterates over [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

```js
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (let item of listItems) {
    console.log('item text:', item.textContent); // "first", "second", "third", "fourth"
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
</ol>
```

### Plain Objects are not normally [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterables) (can't use `for...of`)

Trying to use `for...of` on a plain Object will throw an error.

```js
const obj = { first: 3, second: 5, third: 7, fourth: "hello" };

// with Object.keys()

for (let value of obj) { //This is an error. obj is not iterable
    console.log('value:', value);
}
```

#### Other ways to iterate over Object property values

#### [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

If you are looking for other ways to perform a similar task, [MDN shows examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Examples) of using [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over property values for [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object):

**`forEach` directly over an Object's values obtained form `Object.values()`:**

```js
const obj = { first: 3, second: 5, third: 7, fourth: "hello" };

// with Object.keys()

Object.values(obj).forEach(function (value) {
    console.log('value:', value); // logs "3", "5", "7", "hello"
});
```

**`forEach` over an Object's keys obtained form `Object.keys()`:**

```js
const obj = { first: 3, second: 5, third: 7, fourth: "hello" };

// with Object.keys()

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    //obj[key] is the property value
    console.log('key:', key);        // logs "first", "second", "third", "fourth"
    console.log('value:', obj[key]); // logs "3", "5", "7", "hello"
});
```

**`forEach` over an Array's values:**

```js
const arr = [ 3, 5, 7 ];

arr.forEach(function (value, index) {
    console.log('value:', value);     // logs "3", "5", "7"
    console.log('index:', index);     // logs "0", "1", "2"
});
```

#### [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

The primary drawback to using a `for..in` loop is that it iterates over the Object's [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), which will include properties on the Object's prototype. This can cause unexpected errors. Thus, it's always a good idea to test that the loop's key value is one of the Object's own using [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), or other method, unless you *know* you want to iterate over the enumerable properties which are not the Object's own properties (you rarely want to).

While it's not strictly necessary, it's a good idea to use a known-good copy of `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`, as any Object could define their own `hasOwnProperty`, either intentionally, or by mistake.

```js
const obj = { first: 3, second: 5, third: 7, fourth: "hello" };

// with for..in

for (let key in obj) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
        //obj[key] is the property value
        console.log('key:', key); // logs "first", "second", "third", "fourth"
        console.log('value:', obj[key]); // logs "3", "5", "7", "hello"
    }
}
```

### Browser compatibility:

If you are intending to port your add-on to other browsers, or use `for...of` in a webpage, then you should be aware of when the feature was added to various browsers. As can be seen in the [Browser Compatibility table on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility), the primary issue is that it is not supported by Internet Explorer.

This is the [compatibility table from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility) as of 2018-03-11:

[image: browser compatibility]

1. Chrome 29–37: The `for...of` loop feature is available behind a preference. In chrome://flags, activate the entry “Enable Experimental JavaScript”.
2. Prior to Firefox 51, using the `for...of` loop construct with the `const` keyword threw a SyntaxError ("missing = in const declaration").

Comment: Very useful answer, I didnt know it landed in FF13

Answer (score 1):

It's an EcmaScript 6 feature which is not stable or supported by all modern browsers. You need to wait for it to be stable or you can use a transpiler like [Traceur](https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/demo/repl.html#) which will convert your ES6 code to ES5.

Comment: What do you mean by "not stable"? Also, a transcoder is something else, perhaps you are looking for the word transpiler.

Comment: Can he use `var tab in tabs` for pre-es6 support?

Comment: using `var tab in tabs` or in other words for...in structure is supported in all browsers. you can use safely. by "not stable" I meant that feature is added in some browsers or some versions of some browsers but trusting it's support may not be a good idea for now.