# What is Javascript 'of' operator

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was learning about `Object.entries` in Javascript and I came across the following code snippet:

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}

// expected output:
// "a: somestring"
// "b: 42"
```

we can see that there is a "of " keyword used in here; can anyone tell me how it works?

```
for (const [key, value]  of Object.entries(object1)) {
```

Comment: It's a `for of` loop

Answer (score 1):

The `of` keyword is usually used to iterate through **iterable objects** (in this example you have given, is the object of Object.entries).

For more explanations and examples, you can find out from this documentation by Mozilla.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Edited according to VLAZ comment:
There is no `of` keyword nor is it a standalone thing. It's only a part of `for..of` and `for await..of` statements.

Comment: "*The of keyword is usually used to iterate through iterable objects*" 1. There is no `of` keyword. It's not a standalone thing. It's *only* a part of `for..of` and `for await..of` statements. 2. "usually" implies there are some unusual cases where `for..of` is not used with iterables. Yet, that is its only purpose - It's not possible to use `for..of` with anything that's not iterable.

Comment: @VLAZ edited according to your comments. thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

The for...of loop, which iterates over property values, is a feature added to the JavaScript specification in ECMAScript 2015.

Please look at this post:

[JavaScript `of` Keyword (for...of loops)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525695/javascript-of-keyword-for-of-loops)